Python create custom user inputs to operate a modal operator
If possible, I would like to take control of mouse inputs with the knife tool. I've just learned about modal operators, and I was wondering if it is possible to fire the modal callback somehow and create and supply my own fake mouse input events. If this is possible, are there any documentation links or useful search terms I should be looking for?
My goal is to create an automatic slicing tool that would cut up a large mesh into chunks, currently the most promising path is to somehow create my own curves for the desired cut paths and run it through knife project, I'm pretty confident this approach will work, but I want to also learn as much as possible about the possibilities of blender addons, being able to take control of the mouse will certainly be useful. Thanks!
